# Torch.sort and argsort sorting randomly in case of same element

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, pytorch

When same elements are encountered, torch.sort and argsort sort the tensor in random manner.
This is not the case in numpy.
I have a list of elements already sorted according to the second column and now i want to sort it using the first column but preserve the earlier sort in case of tie in the new sorting.

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor(
        [[ 0., 3.],
        [ 2., 3.],
        [ 2., 2.],
        [10., 2.],
        [ 0., 2.],
        [ 6., 2.],
        [10., 1.],
        [ 2., 1.],
        [ 0., 1.],
        [ 6., 1.],
        [10., 0.],
        [12., 0.]]
)
print(a[torch.argsort(a[:, 0])])
```

Output:

```
tensor([[ 0.,  3.],
        [ 0.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  3.],
        [ 6.,  1.],
        [ 6.,  2.],
        [10.,  1.],
        [10.,  2.],
        [10.,  0.],
        [12.,  0.]])
```

Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
        [[ 0., 3.],
        [ 2., 3.],
        [ 2., 2.],
        [10., 2.],
        [ 0., 2.],
        [ 6., 2.],
        [10., 1.],
        [ 2., 1.],
        [ 0., 1.],
        [ 6., 1.],
        [10., 0.],
        [12., 0.]]
)
print(a[np.argsort(a[:, 0])])
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  3.]
 [ 0.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 2.  3.]
 [ 2.  2.]
 [ 2.  1.]
 [ 6.  2.]
 [ 6.  1.]
 [10.  2.]
 [10.  1.]
 [10.  0.]
 [12.  0.]]
```

What could be the reason for this? And what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: Apparently the sorting algorithm used in PyTorch is not [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).  Note that the default algorithm in NumPy is quicksort, which is also not stable in general--you might have gotten lucky with your example.  In `numpy.sort` and `numpy.argsort`, you can override the default with the `kind` parameter.  (This is not an answer, because I think your real question is "how do I do a stable sort with PyTorch?")

Comment: FYI: a request for a stable sort is an open PyTorch issue: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/28871

Answer (score 2):

As per torch 1.9.0 you can run the sort with option `stable=True`. See https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/generated/torch.sort.html?highlight=sort#torch.sort

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([0, 1] * 9)
>>> x.sort()
torch.return_types.sort(
    values=tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
    indices=tensor([ 2, 16,  4,  6, 14,  8,  0, 10, 12,  9, 17, 15, 13, 11,  7,  5,  3,  1]))
>>> x.sort(stable=True)
torch.return_types.sort(
    values=tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
    indices=tensor([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16,  1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17]))
```

The documentation says this is only on the CPU, but it will come to GPU sorting soon, since that documentation warning has been removed in the master branch at github (as per https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/61685)